# Drupal 8 .install

Tags: drupal-8

Is it proper to place a namespace call in your drupal .install file?  I have a module and was using some standard functions such as

```
function setup_content() {
  <do some functions to setup sample content>
  return;
}
```

The purpose was to install some content and do some other setup of the module.  I used this function in multiple .install files and started getting an error that it was declared multiple times.

I tested putting a namespace call into the module and it fixed it but I was not sure if that was proper.  I read over this page https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/namespaces and was not able to determine if I should do that are not.

Basically is there an issue with declaring a namespace in the .install which will remove the .install code from the global namespace?

Thanks

Comment: You should use function yourmodule_install(), and all your function should start from yourmodule_functionname() prefix.

Comment: So instead of setup_content() I should create the function like mymodule_setupcontent()?  I can understand that.  That would negate the need for the namespace.